# Маршрутизация филиалов

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, маршрутизация, ubuntu, сервер

Здравствуйте! Проблема с маршрутизацией сети филиала. Есть VPN сервер на 2008r2, и есть VPN клиент на Ubuntu Server (он же шлюз в удаленной сети). Нужно что бы локальная сеть с r2 vpn сервером, видела сеть с Ubuntu сервером.

> 192.168.192.0/24  - Win2008r2
> 192.168.192.20        - Ubuntu VPN client
> 192.168.20.0/24       - Ubuntu

Для этого на Ubuntu разрешаю FORWARD с vpn интерфейса (вообще от безграмотности и неопытности разрешил все с и на vpn интерфейс что б наверняка), и на Win2008r2 прописал маршрут:

> route add 192.168.20.0/24192.168.192.20

После чего tracert 192.168.20.1, говорит "Общий сбой"

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем может быть проблема ?

**upd:**
Может ли проблема быть из-за того что vpn клиенты получают ip адреса из диапазона локальной сети ?

**upd2:**
Да, действительно, VPN сервер выдавая IP из локального диапазона, прописывал маршрут вида:

> route add 192.168.192.20/32 192.168.192.20 IF <интерфейс VPN сервера>

ну а после того как я прописывал маршрут через этот IP до другой подсети, всё запутывалось, так как *наверное* первым шагом искался этот IP (192.168.192.20) в локальной подсети (192.168.192.1), *наверное* если изменить метрику всё бы заработало:

> route change 192.168.192.0/24 metric 30
> route change 192.168.192.20/32 metric 20

но я проверять не стал и от греха подальше перевел VPN клиентов в другую подсеть.
**[вопрос закрыт]**
p.s. [[@pyatak](/users/814/pyatak)](/users/814/pyatak), спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно сделал, скорее всего, забыл прописать  маршрут сети  к 192.168.192.0/24 на Ubuntu VPN client.

Comment: нет, из сети за убунту к сети 192.168.192.0/24 всё нормально ходит((